# trying to call api but its giving me connection refuse

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my code where am using http module to call the api inside the promise but not able make
any api call its just giving 500 err

```
 const dataString = JSON.stringify(consentDetail)
    console.log("dataString",dataString)
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': dataString.length
        }
      }

    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req =  https.get("URL", options, (res) => {

            let finalData = "";

            res.on("data", function(data){
                finalData += data.toString();
            })

            res.on("end", () => {
                var data = JSON.parse(finalData);
                resolve({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
                })
            })

        })
        req.on('error', (err) => {
            reject({
                statusCode: 500,
                body: err
            });
          })

    })

    return response;
```

and I want call the api using only http or https without having to install any npm package

Comment: By 'call' do you mean you want to get information from the API, or put new information into the API?

Comment: @Pandamora yes and actually I want to make a post api which was not working so tried to just simply a call a api which is also giving err

Comment: You wanted to get information from the API, right?

Comment: @Pandamora yes that is what I am looking for

Comment: In your options variable, you state a 'POST' request - try changing it to 'GET'

Comment: nope that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you will need to change in your code. First, the API you are calling is expecting a GET request, so you have to change that in your 'options' object. And since you're going to send a GET request, the headers 'Content-Type' and 'Content-Length' need to be removed.

Also, there is no 'url' option for the 'options' in the http module. This is why you are receiving a 500 response. Since no url/host were provided to the http module, it is attempting to connect to http://127.0.0.1:80. The correct way is to use the parameters 'host' and 'path', like this:

```js
const options = {
    host: 'catfact.ninja',
    path: '/fact',
    method: 'GET'
}
```

or include the url as the first parameter in the get method, like this:

```js
const req =  http.get('http://catfact.ninja/fact', options, (res) => {
...
}
```

By doing so, you will see that we now receive a new error:

```
undefined:1                                                                                  
<html>                                                                                       
^                                                                                            
                                                                                             
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0                                        
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)                                                              
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\...\index.js:18:33) 
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)                                               
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)                                  
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

The reason for this is that we are receiving a html response instead of a JSON. Looking further into the response, we can see that we actually received a 301 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Wed, 29 Dec 2021 19:24:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://catfact.ninja/fact
```

The 301 redirects to the https protocol, meaning the API doesn't support http requests anymore. So let's use https instead. Just use the https built-in module instead of the http one, and change the URL to https://catfact.ninja/fact. No other changes to the code are necessary.

So, the final code should be:

```js
const options = {
    method: 'GET'
}

const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req =  https.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact', options, (res) => {
        let finalData = "";

        res.on("data", function(data){
            finalData += data.toString();
        })

        res.on("end", () => {
            var data = JSON.parse(finalData);
            resolve({
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
            })
        })
    })
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        reject({
            statusCode: 500,
            body: err
        });
    })
})

return response;
```

Comment: Hi, actually I wanted to make post api and when calling the api with headers it gives ERROR and without header its not working headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': dataString.length
        }

Comment: The catfact.ninja API doesn't accept POST requests, only GET. You can see it in their documentation: https://catfact.ninja/. Or was it only an example, and you actually meant another generic URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `https.request` and options pass host and path.

**check here:**
https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpsrequestoptions-callback

```
const dataString = JSON.stringify(consentDetail);
console.log("dataString", dataString);
const options = {
  // Update here
  hostname: "hostname",
  path: "/path",

  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": dataString.length,
  },
};

const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // update here 
  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let finalData = "";
    res.on("data", function (data) {
      finalData += data.toString();
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
      var data = JSON.parse(finalData);
      resolve({
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
    });
  });
  req.on("error", (err) => {
    reject({
      statusCode: 500,
      body: err,
    });
  });
});

return response;
```

Comment: yes I tried that way also  still giving the error as "ECONNRESET"